# UISearchBar graphical issue

Tags: ios, storyboard, uisearchbar

Can someone tell me, why when I set UISearchBar Search Style to Minimal, I've got strange white bracket near "x" button??

[image: Original bug image]

Both simulator and device.
How to handle that crap?

Answer:
Some time ago I had task to change UISearchBar's cancel button title, and placed following code to make it:

[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"searchbar.cancelButton.title", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];

And this is the exact reason of this graphical bug. As you can see from view hierarchy, even with DISABLED "Show cancel button", the cancel button still exist and even not hided. The "bracket" is actually half "O" from new button title "Отмена".

[image: View Hierarchy Screenshot]

Comment: debug your hierarchy views and check if there is a view over?

Comment: On a new project I don't have that issue. As @ReinierMelian suggested, try the debug view hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks you, guys. I found the bug! I've edited original post with answer.